# Не удается удалить двумерный массив в СИ

Tags: c, массивы, free

в своей программы я создаю матрицу N*N+1, заполняю ее нулями, а потом удаляю этот массив полностью. Но возникла маленькая проблема: при выполнении последнего free программы выдает исключение "Нарушение прав доступа по записи".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int n;
    printf("Введите количество неизвестых: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n, 1);
    double** array = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * n); // создание 
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
        array[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * (n + 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) { // заполнение единицами
            array[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {  //вывод
            printf("%lf ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    // Очистим память
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        free(array[i]);
    free(array);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Буду благодарен за разъяснение

Comment: Выход за пределы массива...

Comment: Причем в остальных циклах (кроме последнего) у вас этой ошибки нет. Вы самостоятельно, без "помощи клуба", не можете заметить очевидную разницу между вашими же циклами? И откуда взялось такое разнообразие условий цикла: `i < n + 1`, `i < n`, `i <= n`? Три разных человека писало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создается массив с `n` элементами

```
double** array = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * n); // создание
```

Затем делается запись в `n + 1` элемент

```
for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
  array[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * (n + 1));
```

Получается вылет за пределы массива.

Comment: И в очистке тоже выход за пределы массива. n массивов, а в цикле условие i <= n.

Comment: @Not Bjarne Stroustrup: Пусть это и неправильно, но зато справедливо!!1 Раз выделяли `n + 1`, то и освобождать нужно `n + 1` !!11 (шутка)

Comment: Я уже запутался в край, что мне исправить?

Comment: @Руслан Мамедов: Исправлять всегда лучше самую первую ошибку (см. мой ответ), а далее уже искать следующие.

Comment: @AnT Так он выделил массив из n указателей, а удаляет n + 1? Или я не прав? (Вопрос без шуток)

Comment: @Not Bjarne Stroustrup: Разумеется, вы правы. Исправлять нужно и первый, и последний цикл. И там, и там условие должно быть `i < n`.

Comment: Разобрался, большое спасибо, больше не повторится))